# Run through a vector of member functions in boost for_each

Tags: c++, boost, stl, lambda, bind

I try to learn boost lambda expressions, and this is a thing that doesn't work out.

How can I run in the for_each a selected member of Holder?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/assign.hpp> 
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;
using namespace boost::lambda;

class Holder
{
public:
    void vRun1(std::string s){ cout << "vRun1 " << s << endl; }
    void vRun2(std::string s){ cout << "vRun2 " << s << endl; }
    void vRun3(std::string s){ cout << "vRun3 " << s << endl; }
};

// --------------------
std::map< std::string, mem_fun_ref_t<void, Holder> > replacer;


insert(replacer)
        ("buh", std::mem_fun_ref(&Holder::vRun1))
        ("mar", std::mem_fun_ref(&Holder::vRun2))
        ("heu", std::mem_fun_ref(&Holder::vRun3));


Holder hol;
```

How do I call here the functions I have registered in the `map<>`?

```
for_each(replacer.begin(), replacer.end(), /* bind(_1, hol, it.first) */ );
```

The result should be

```
vRun1 buh
vRun2 mar
vRun3 heu
```

Comment: The map iterator when de-reference is a `std::pair<std::string, mem_fun_ref_t<void, Holder> >`

Comment: `bind((*_1).second,hol, (*_1).first)` doesn't help

Comment: I would try a for loop, but my compiler does not support C++11 yet :(

Comment: vasile for loop has been in ANSI C since the beginning

Comment: `(*_1).second` won't work for binding. I believe the correct syntax is `bind(&replacer::value_type::second, *_1)`, so the composed bind expression should be `bind(bind(&replacer::value_type::second, *_1), hol, bind(&replacer::value_type::first))`. All in all it's not easier than the way in sehe's answer.

Comment: @sehe My previous comment was refering to two separate comments above - why not a for loop, and why not cxx11 lambdas. It would be hard for a programmer to miss the for loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though you are overcomplicating it slightly. I'd use `boost::function<>` like so:

See it live on **http://liveworkspace.org/code/b2c5a38d8c3499eefb6330a839a89d0a**

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
using namespace std;

class Holder {
public:
    void vRun1(std::string s){ cout << "vRun1 " << s << endl; }
    void vRun2(std::string s){ cout << "vRun2 " << s << endl; }
    void vRun3(std::string s){ cout << "vRun3 " << s << endl; }
};

typedef std::map< std::string, boost::function<void(Holder&, std::string)> > Replacer;

int main()
{
    Replacer replacer;
    replacer["a"] = &Holder::vRun1;
    replacer["b"] = &Holder::vRun2;
    replacer["c"] = &Holder::vRun3;

    Holder hol;

    for (Replacer::const_iterator it=replacer.begin(); it != replacer.end(); ++it)
    {
        (it->second)(hol, it->first);
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
    std::cout << "Using BOOST_FOREACH:\n";

    BOOST_FOREACH(Replacer::value_type& pair, replacer)
    {
        (pair.second)(hol, pair.first);
    }
```

Or even:

```
    std::cout << "Using Boost Phoenix:\n";

    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    using namespace phx::arg_names;

    std::for_each(replacer.begin(), replacer.end(),
            phx::bind(
                phx::bind(&Replacer::value_type::second, arg1), 
                phx::ref(hol), 
                phx::bind(&Replacer::value_type::first, arg1)));
}
```

Outputs

```
vRun1 a
vRun2 b
vRun3 c
Using BOOST_FOREACH:
vRun1 a
vRun2 b
vRun3 c
Using Boost Phoenix:
vRun1 a
vRun2 b
vRun3 c
```

Comment: @vasile Added the actual BOOST_FOREACH variation too for completeness (and got rid of the now useless `mem_fun_ref` stuff)

Comment: @n.m. I also fought for a good hour and (with [some help](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/binding-over-a-map-of-member-functions)) came up with a Phoenix bind incantation that looks slightly less daunting :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;

class Holder
{
public:
    void vRun1(std::string s){ std::cout << "vRun1 " << s << std::endl; }
    void vRun2(std::string s){ std::cout << "vRun2 " << s << std::endl; }
    void vRun3(std::string s){ std::cout << "vRun3 " << s << std::endl; }
};

// --------------------
typedef std::map <std::string, 
                  boost::function<void(Holder&, std::string)> > Replacer_t;
Replacer_t replacer;
typedef Replacer_t::value_type ReplacerValue_t;

int main()
{
    boost::assign::insert(replacer)
        (std::string("buh"), &Holder::vRun1)
        (std::string("mar"), &Holder::vRun2)
        (std::string("heu"), &Holder::vRun3);


    Holder hol;

    for_each(replacer.begin(),
             replacer.end(),
             bind(protect(bind(bind(&ReplacerValue_t::second,_2),
                               _1,
                               bind(&ReplacerValue_t::first,_2))),
                  boost::ref(hol), _1));
}
```

This took about 2 hours of fighting with boost::lambda. In C++11 I would write it in 30 seconds, so update your compilers accordingly.

Comment: Erm... Impressive. Also, a good time to write a functor, I'd say :) Still impressive.